# Defining custom css properties in Flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, mxml

I'm creating a Flex theme and I'm defining the default component appearance. All buttons should have a default skin. A special style can be applied to the buttons using styleName, which defines a set of colors to the button skin.

I have created a Spark Button skin as follows:

```
<!-- ButtonSkin.mxml -->

<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" minWidth="21" minHeight="24" alpha.disabled="0.5">

    <fx:Metadata>
        <![CDATA[
            [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
            [Style(name="backgroundGradient", states="up, over, down", format="Array", inherit="yes")]
        ]]>
    </fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
            {
                var backgroundGradient:Array = getStyle("backgroundGradient");
                topGradientEntry.color = backgroundGradient[0];
                bottomGradientEntry.color = backgroundGradient[1];

                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="up" />
        <s:State name="over" />
        <s:State name="down" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
    </s:states>

    <!-- shapes using topGradientEntry.color and bottomGradientEntry.color -->
</s:Skin>
```

set the main css file like this:

```
/** default.css **/

s|Button {
    skinClass: ClassReference('mytheme.skins.ButtonSkin');
    fontWeight: bold;
}

skins|ButtonSkin {
    backgroundGradient: 0x000000, 0xFFFFFF;
}

s|Button.btn-primary:up {
    backgroundGradient: 0x000000, 0xFFFFFF;
}
s|Button.btn-primary:over {
    backgroundGradient: 0x000000, 0xFFFFFF;
}
s|Button.btn-primary:down {
    backgroundGradient: 0x000000, 0xFFFFFF;
}

s|Button.btn-inverted:up {
    backgroundGradient: 0xFFFFFF, 0x000000;
}
s|Button.btn-inverted:over {
    backgroundGradient: 0xFFFFFF, 0x000000;
}
s|Button.btn-inverted:down {
    backgroundGradient: 0xFFFFFF, 0x000000;
}
```

The application would style the buttons like this:

```
<!-- Main.mxml -->

<s:Button label="Default" x="10" y="10" width="75" height="26"/>
<s:Button label="Button" x="110" y="10" width="75" height="26" styleName="btn-success"/>
<s:Button label="Primary" x="210" y="10" width="75" height="26" styleName="btn-primary"/>
```

But I'm getting the error "CSS Value for 'backgroundGradient' not supported" on all occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe how much time I spent on this issue. The problem is that values in CSS should use the HEX with # format i.e. #FFFFFF and not 0xFFFFFF. Actionscript uses the 0x format, MXML uses both, and CSS uses the HEX with # format.